# How to generate a custom Zend filter from a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, zend-filter

I want to realize a Zend_Filter that return the string replacing banks with underscore and remove all the characters not allowed in a regular expression.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$filter = new Zend_Filter_PregReplace();
$filter->setMatchPattern(array(' ', '/regexForCaracterNotAllowed/'))
       ->setReplacement(array('_', ''));
```

This is how to use the Zend_Filter_PregReplace. What are the not allowed caracters?

Comment: +1 nice! This was very helpful, you saved me 5 - 10 minutes of searching which I didn't feel like doing.